# Kubernetes only run specific deployments on nodes by specific label

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

Using Kubernetes I have a set of nodes that are high cpu and I am using a affinity policy for a given deployment to specifically target these high cpu nodes:

```
# deployment.yaml
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: high-cpu-node
            operator: In
            values:
            - "true"
```

That works, however it does not prevent all the rest of the deployments from scheduling pods on these high cpu nodes. How do I specify that these high cpu nodes should ONLY run pods where `high-cpu-node=true`? Is it possible to do this without going and modifying all the other deployment configurations *(I have dozens of deployments)*?

Answer (score 1):

To get this behaviour you should taint nodes and use tolerations on deployments: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/

But, unfortunately, you would have to modify deployments. It's not possible to achieve this simply via labels.